# Support of dotnet core on Raspberry Zero through Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core

As you can read [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/447#issuecomment-307401355), dotnet core isn't supported on a Raspberry Zero because of the missing armv7 instructions on the Zero.

However, I wanted to use the Zero because of it's small form factor to monitor a couple of sensors which would be built inside a 3d printed "boat" that you can put in the water so it can monitor things like pH, temperature, salinity, etc. etc.

I am very new to docker and I was wondering if I could use it to circumvent this limitation. So could I publish a dotnet core app running in a docker container on a Raspberry Zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Docker is not an emulator or a Virtual Machine. It can only execute (assembly) instructions that target the processor that docker is running on. If .NET Core doesn't run because the arm processor does not support certain instructions then docker won't fix that.

If you really want to use Zero, then you will need to look into another programming language.

Comment: I feared this was the case. :(